# Data Validation in play Framework-java 2.4

Tags: java, json, validation, playframework-2.4

How to Use Play Validation Framework to validate data coming from incoming 
"POST" web service? And What are the different ways to do it? And where should i validate my data : in Controller or in Service layer?
I am using "play.data.validation.Validation".But not working. I am new to play framework. I am using play 2.4 with java (not scala).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [play.data.Form](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaForms) to bind data from request to a `pojo` class. Form fields can be annotated with different constraints. If one of them fails, form will contain errors:

```
Form<YourClass> form = Form.form(YourClass.class).bindFromRequest();
 if (form.hasErrors()) {
     return badRequest();
 } else {
     ...
 }
```

Your `pojo` class:

```
public class YourClass {

    @Required
    private Long id;

    // setters, getters

}
```

> And where should i validate my data : in Controller or in Service layer?

I prefer to validate the data before I move to service layer. Otherwise, your service layer has to handle `bad data` scenario and return adequate response to controller layer.